# Store list into map

Tags: java, collections

[Can you help me to get what was wrong with the below program]

Code

```
    List<String> fruitsList= new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("mango", "apple", "grapes","MANGO", "APPLE", "GRAPES"));
    Map<String, List<String>> fruitMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : fruitsList) {

        if (fruitMap.get(s.toLowerCase())==null) {

            fruitMap.put(s.toLowerCase(), Collections.singletonList(s));
        } else {
             fruitMap.get(s.toLowerCase()).add(s);  // got error at this line
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fruitMap);
```

Expected map:
{apple=[apple,APPLE], mango=[mango,MANGO], grapes=[grapes,GRAPES]}]

Comment: here is error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)

Comment: Update your question with the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Collections.singletonList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-) returns an immutable list and hence you cannot add elements into it. Create a list which is mutable.

Simplifying it,

```
if (fruitMap.get(s.toLowerCase()) == null) {
    fruitMap.put(s.toLowerCase(), new LinkedList<>());
}
fruitMap.get(s.toLowerCase()).add(s);
```

Or you can use [Map#computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

```
fruitMap.computeIfAbsent(s.toLowerCase(), k -> new LinkedList<>()).add(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to add elements to `singletonList` because such list is immutable.

Thus, usual implementation of list is needed:

```java
List<String> fruitsList = Arrays.asList("mango", "apple", "grapes","MANGO", "APPLE", "GRAPES");
Map<String, List<String>> fruitMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String s : fruitsList) {
    fruitMap.computeIfAbsent(s.toLowerCase(), (key) -> new ArrayList<>()).add(s);
}
System.out.println(fruitMap);
```

Or Stream API may be used using simple `Collectors.groupingBy`:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> fruitMapStream = fruitsList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase));
System.out.println(fruitMapStream);
```

Output:

```
{apple=[apple, APPLE], grapes=[grapes, GRAPES], mango=[mango, MANGO]}
{apple=[apple, APPLE], grapes=[grapes, GRAPES], mango=[mango, MANGO]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a grouping excercise:

```
fruitsList.stream().collect(groupingBy(fruit -> fruit.toLowerCase()));
```

The classfier function in this case is: All fruits that are the same when converted to lower case go into the same group.